# Change point colour based on value for Google Scatter Chart

Tags: google-visualization, scatter-plot

I am creating a Google scatter chart. I have one data series which looks something like:

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

data.addRows([[1,100], [2,150], 
              [3,200], [4,250], 
              [5,300], [6,350],
              [7,400], [8,450]]);
```

I want the colour of the points on the scatter chart to vary, between green and red, based on the 'Value' of each point.

i.e. the colour of point ID=1 should be green, however ID=8 should be red!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add an extra column to your DataTable, with the role style :

```js
data.addColumn( {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'} );
```

Now add styling to each of the rows to get the desired effect :

```js
data.addRows([[1,100, 'point {size: 14; fill-color: green'], 
              [2,150, 'point {size: 14; fill-color: green'], 
              ....
              [8,450, 'point {size: 14; fill-color: red']
             ]);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v92k8rty/**

---

**Update**. There is one (out of probably hundreds) javascript library that very easily can provide a gradient palette with customizeable colors and range - [**RainbowVis-JS**](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS). Instead of the above, create a palette by using RainbowVis in the same range as the DataTable, and then add the colors dynamically :

```js
//create a gradient palette from green to red using RainbowVis
var rainbow = new Rainbow(); 
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, data.getNumberOfRows());
rainbow.setSpectrum('green', 'red');

//alter the DataTable
data.addColumn( {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'} );    
for (var i=0;i<data.getNumberOfRows();i++) {
    data.setCell(i, 2, 'point { fill-color:'+rainbow.colorAt(i+1)+'}');
}
```

[image]
demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ehgfwh8z/**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, perhaps I was not clear enough in my question. I was hoping to create a gradient of colour throughout the range of Values. An example of what I am after would be on this page: [link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) note how the colours have a gradient i.e Russia's popularity is greater than the US' so it is darker. My data has several thousand values so it will not be possible to manually assign a colour to each.

Comment: @AnPocArBuile, yes - you forgot to mention some details in the question, to say it the least :)  See update.

Comment: This is very helpful, doesn't work on material scatter chart though.