# programmatically color points in google scatter chart

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have a table in a google sheet

```
00   60    243 234 100
00   46    243 253 132
10   24    213 243 251
14   44    231 253 111
```

etc. etc.

I'd like to scatter plot the first column as my X axis, second column as my Y axis and the other three columns as RGB values that give a specific color to each point.

I have looked for answers for the past umpteen hours and all I could see that if I use "JavaScript" then there are these Google Chart Tools and it appears that they give the full control over items like point colors (e.g. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380320/change-point-colour-based-on-value-for-google-scatter-chart)).

But I don't understand how to use "JavaScript" with my google sheet, as all I know is a "Google Script" tool where I can code Google Script functions, and all these new google.Visualization.... stuff doesn't work at all.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this chart problem?

EDIT1:
An example googlesheet along with the bound Google Script.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hxaRvWzw3lpCGLHKn95RJWP1yJhX3JckcRrhv3SIzos/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create the chart you are looking for.

As of now, the Sheets Charts are unable to create multiple-series charts from single points and the Google Charts library is also unable to do so.

You could use an external library and insert it as a [sidebar or dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) in your sheet with a custom function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the response and I tried your suggestions. Indeed I can create a custom dialog or sidebar where I can display the Html page contents. The annoying thing is that I am forced to trigger the dialog from the Custom Menu each time. I added an html page inside the script editor and used an example from Google to display a plot of random points. Now I am trying to figure out how I can populate those hard coded numbers dynamically, by reading them from my spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hxaRvWzw3lpCGLHKn95RJWP1yJhX3JckcRrhv3SIzos/edit#gid=0

Comment: To do that you have to insert the data into your HTML page. You can do that with [HtmlTemplates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).